# Spacy: what dataset format to categorize 1000 labels?

Tags: spacy, multilabel-classification, spacy-3

I want to categorize text with spacy
I'm based on the spacy's texcat_demo project, and based on it, the json should looks like this

```
{"text": "Sorpresa: Ceferin comió con Piqué y Laporta",   "cats": {"AR": 0, "ES": 1, "PT": 0 } } 
{"text": "Puado, de calabazas al Madrid a una renovación prioritaria","cats": {"AR": 0, "ES": 1, "PT": 0 } }
```

But how should looks this json to multiple categories?, like this

```
 {"text": "Sorpresa: Ceferin comió con Piqué y Laporta",   "cats": {"content": "news", "language": "spanish" } }
 {"text": "Puado, de calabazas al Madrid a una renovación prioritaria", "cats": {"content": "soccer", "language": "portuguese" } }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked [the same question](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8438) on the spaCy forum, but I'll go ahead and answer here: the format is the same no matter how many labels you have. (Is there a reason you though otherwise? I don't think we said there was a limit anywhere...)

Also note the JSON format is not a fixed format, the important thing is creating the Doc object before serializing it. There are many ways to do that but there are examples in the [spaCy tutorial projects](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8438).